# Passing arguments to Class-based node module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this Node.js module structure:

```
class Foo {

  log() {
    console.log(this.bar); // should log 'hello'
  }
}

module.exports = new Foo;
```

How can I 'require' the above and pass 'bar' as argument?

E.g something along these lines:

```
var Foo = require("./foo.js")("hello");
```

---

I'm specifically interested in how to do this with Class-based modules.

---

**Update: Class-based *Singletons* are a *Bad Idea™***. I've switched to the object-literal module structure instead.

Comment: Never export class instances. Either use object literals (for singletons), or export the class itself.

Comment: Removing the parenthesis doesn't change anything, it's the `new` that you need to avoid!

Comment: 'new' or 'literal' are the same,  they all instantiate an object and set the members and values, no need to be afraid of `new`, so you can do one of these: `let foo = new Object({ name: "fooInstance", type: "someObject" });` or: `let foo = { name: "fooInstance", type: "someObject" };` or `let foo = new Foo("fooInstance",  "someObject");` and it will all be the same all will return true to:  `foo instanceof Object` (beside obviously  the last example all others will return false on `foo instanceof Foo`) and they all execute the Object constructor, and return a reference to that created instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your `foo.js` to export the class, not an instance of it, and add a constructor which would assign the first argument to `this.bar`:

```
class Foo {
  constructor(bar) {
    this.bar = bar;
  }

  log() {
    console.log(this.bar); // should log 'hello'
  }
}

module.exports = Foo;
```

Then you can use it like that:

```
var foo = new (require("./foo.js"))("hello");
foo.log();
```

Comment: doesn't answers the OP question, just show how to export a class, and not the instance (see my comment to @ant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36371526/530884)

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing class and module definitions. You don't export an instance. You export a definition which you instantiate after you import it. Then you have to call a function

If you're using the ECMA2015 classes, then you can just write:

```
export default class Foo {
  constructor(bar) {
    this._bar = bar; 
  }

  log() {
    console.log(this._bar);
  }
}
```

Then your calling code should look like this:

```
import Foo from './foo.js';
let foo = new Foo('Boom!'); 
foo.log();
```

The import keyword is used like require in ES5.

Comment: I'm quite sure I'm not mixing them up - requiring the way i posed it in my question will also *instantiate* the imported definition. The problem is that I can't pass arguments directly from the `require` statement to the constructor. There are many ways to do what I want but I specifically want to do just that - instantiate with arguments using a single-lined `require`

Comment: Yes, but you have to instantiate it with the argument. You can't call new in the export and then try to pass a constructor argument in your variable declaration.

Comment: No I don't. The code I posted instantiates itself (for lack of a better expression), on `require`, as a singleton. There is no need to re-instantiate it using `new`. It's exported as an instance already. I think the way I'm doing things doesn't allow to do what I want so I've switched to a different pattern. Thanks anyway

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides: If you want a singleton, you should not use a `class`.

Comment: @Bergi and that's what I did. I've marked @Gothdo answer as correct since it's the only one that instantiates in a single-lined `require`. Looks like it's a horrible anti-pattern but it answers the question in the best way.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides: Instantiating right after the `require` call is OK, instantiating before exporting is a problem.

Comment: you CAN export a var or an instance to share a single instance to all modules importing this module in the same runtime env, thus acheiving a singleton and turning class into a private (no other module can access it), the question remains - how to pass a module parameters ?

Answer (score 0):

## Method 1:

create a module that will have only one instance from the class it contains on all modules,

lets call it `level-driver.js`:

```
const level = require('level-party'); // used for local lightweight db (google's leveldb) with multi process connection

class LevelDriver
{
    constructor(dbPath)
    {
        // connect to the local leveldb using json schema
        this.db = level(dbPath);
    }
    
    ...
}

// singleton instance holder
let instance = null;

function levelDriver(dbPath)
{
    if(instance == null)
    {
        // create an instance of LevelDriver
        instance = new LevelDriver(dbPath);
    }
    return instance;
}

// export only the instance (not the object) so it will be a singleton
// to all requireing modules (no matter the name or path)
module.exports = levelDriver;
```

then use it like this:

```
const levelDriver = require('./level-driver')('./users/users-db'); // manages leveldb connection and actions
```

## Method 2:

```
const level = require('level-party'); // used for local lightweight db (google's leveldb) with multi process connection

class LevelDriver
{ 
    constructor(dbPath)
    {
        // connect to the local leveldb using json schema
        this.db = level(dbPath);
    }

    ...
}

// export only the instance (not the object) so it will be a singleton
// to all requireing modules (no matter the name or path)
module.exports = (dbPath) => { return new LevelDriver(dbPath) }
```

then use it like this:

```
const levelDriver = require('./level-driver')('./users/users-db'); // manages leveldb connection and actions
```